# Use previous data to sequentially perform calculations and populate future values by group in R

Tags: r, time-series, sequence, lag

I have data that looks like:

```
intial<-
  tibble(
start_date=
  rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-06-01"),as.Date("2021-10-01"),by="months"),4),
end_date=
  rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-07-01"),as.Date("2021-11-01"),by="months"),4),
id=
  rep(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),2),
group=
  c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),
increase=
  c(
    c(4:8),
    c(5:9),
    c(6:10),
    c(7:11)
  ),
decrease=
  c(
    c(1:5),
    c(2:6),
    c(3:7),
    c(4:8)
  ),
start_count=
  c(c(10,13,NA,NA,NA),c(15,18,NA,NA,NA),c(20,23,NA,NA,NA),c(25,28,NA,NA,NA)),
end_count=
  c(c(13,16,NA,NA,NA),c(18,21,NA,NA,NA),c(23,26,NA,NA,NA),c(28,31,NA,NA,NA))
)
print(initial)
 start_date end_date      id group increase decrease start_count end_count
   <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>    <int>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 a            4        1          10        13
 2 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 a            5        2          13        16
 3 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 a            6        3          NA        NA
 4 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 a            7        4          NA        NA
 5 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 a            8        5          NA        NA
 6 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 a            5        2          15        18
 7 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 a            6        3          18        21
 8 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 a            7        4          NA        NA
 9 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 a            8        5          NA        NA
10 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 a            9        6          NA        NA
11 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 b            6        3          20        23
12 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 b            7        4          23        26
13 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 b            8        5          NA        NA
14 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 b            9        6          NA        NA
15 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 b           10        7          NA        NA
16 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 b            7        4          25        28
17 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 b            8        5          28        31
18 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 b            9        6          NA        NA
19 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 b           10        7          NA        NA
20 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 b           11        8          NA        NA
```

My goal is to populate each missing `start_count` and `end_count` by sequentially populating the missing `start_count` with the previous month's `end_count`, and calculate the subsequent `end_count` with the newly populated `start_count` by `start_count` + `increase` - `decrease` within each unique `id` `group`.

The final result should look like:

```
final<-
tibble(
start_date=
  rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-06-01"),as.Date("2021-10-01"),by="months"),4),
end_date=
  rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-07-01"),as.Date("2021-11-01"),by="months"),4),
id=
  rep(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),2),
group=
  c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),
increase=
  c(
    c(4:8),
    c(5:9),
    c(6:10),
    c(7:11)
  ),
decrease=
  c(
    c(1:5),
    c(2:6),
    c(3:7),
    c(4:8)
  ),
start_count=
  c(c(10,13,16,19,22),c(15,18,21,24,27),c(20,23,26,29,32),c(25,28,31,34,37)),
end_count=
  c(c(13,16,19,22,25),c(18,21,24,27,30),c(23,26,29,32,35),c(28,31,34,37,40))
)
print(final)
  start_date end_date      id group increase decrease start_count end_count
   <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>    <int>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 a            4        1          10        13
 2 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 a            5        2          13        16
 3 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 a            6        3          16        19
 4 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 a            7        4          19        22
 5 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 a            8        5          22        25
 6 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 a            5        2          15        18
 7 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 a            6        3          18        21
 8 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 a            7        4          21        24
 9 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 a            8        5          24        27
10 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 a            9        6          27        30
11 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 b            6        3          20        23
12 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 b            7        4          23        26
13 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 b            8        5          26        29
14 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 b            9        6          29        32
15 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 b           10        7          32        35
16 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 b            7        4          25        28
17 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 b            8        5          28        31
18 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 b            9        6          31        34
19 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 b           10        7          34        37
20 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 b           11        8          37        40
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. There might be better ones.

```r
library(tidyverse)

initial<-
    tibble(
        start_date=
            rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-06-01"),as.Date("2021-10-01"),by="months"),4),
        end_date=
            rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-07-01"),as.Date("2021-11-01"),by="months"),4),
        id=
            rep(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),2),
        group=
            c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)),
        increase=
            c(
                c(4:8),
                c(5:9),
                c(6:10),
                c(7:11)
            ),
        decrease=
            c(
                c(1:5),
                c(2:6),
                c(3:7),
                c(4:8)
            ),
        start_count=
            c(c(10,13,NA,NA,NA),c(15,18,NA,NA,NA),c(20,23,NA,NA,NA),c(25,28,NA,NA,NA)),
        end_count=
            c(c(13,16,NA,NA,NA),c(18,21,NA,NA,NA),c(23,26,NA,NA,NA),c(28,31,NA,NA,NA))
    )

initial %>%
    rowid_to_column(var = "obs_id") %>%
    mutate(net = increase - decrease) %>%
    
    select(obs_id, id, group, everything()) %>%
    arrange(id, group, start_date) %>%
    
    group_by(id, group) %>%
    mutate(end_count = cumsum(net) + first(start_count)) %>%
    mutate(start_count = end_count - net) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    
    arrange(obs_id) %>%
    select(-net)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 9
#>    obs_id    id group start_date end_date   increase decrease start_count
#>     <int> <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>        <int>    <int>       <dbl>
#>  1      1     1 a     2021-06-01 2021-07-01        4        1          10
#>  2      2     1 a     2021-07-01 2021-08-01        5        2          13
#>  3      3     1 a     2021-08-01 2021-09-01        6        3          16
#>  4      4     1 a     2021-09-01 2021-10-01        7        4          19
#>  5      5     1 a     2021-10-01 2021-11-01        8        5          22
#>  6      6     2 a     2021-06-01 2021-07-01        5        2          15
#>  7      7     2 a     2021-07-01 2021-08-01        6        3          18
#>  8      8     2 a     2021-08-01 2021-09-01        7        4          21
#>  9      9     2 a     2021-09-01 2021-10-01        8        5          24
#> 10     10     2 a     2021-10-01 2021-11-01        9        6          27
#> 11     11     1 b     2021-06-01 2021-07-01        6        3          20
#> 12     12     1 b     2021-07-01 2021-08-01        7        4          23
#> 13     13     1 b     2021-08-01 2021-09-01        8        5          26
#> 14     14     1 b     2021-09-01 2021-10-01        9        6          29
#> 15     15     1 b     2021-10-01 2021-11-01       10        7          32
#> 16     16     2 b     2021-06-01 2021-07-01        7        4          25
#> 17     17     2 b     2021-07-01 2021-08-01        8        5          28
#> 18     18     2 b     2021-08-01 2021-09-01        9        6          31
#> 19     19     2 b     2021-09-01 2021-10-01       10        7          34
#> 20     20     2 b     2021-10-01 2021-11-01       11        8          37
#> # … with 1 more variable: end_count <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This gets the job done perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `accumulate2` from `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

intial %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  mutate(end_count = accumulate2(increase[-1], decrease[-1], ~ ..1 + ..2 - ..3, .init = first(end_count)) %>%
           flatten_dbl) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(start_count = lag(end_count, default = first(start_count)))
```

**Output**

```
   start_date end_date      id group increase decrease start_count end_count
   <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>    <int>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 a            4        1          10        13
 2 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 a            5        2          13        16
 3 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 a            6        3          16        19
 4 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 a            7        4          19        22
 5 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 a            8        5          22        25
 6 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 a            5        2          25        18
 7 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 a            6        3          18        21
 8 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 a            7        4          21        24
 9 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 a            8        5          24        27
10 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 a            9        6          27        30
11 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 b            6        3          30        23
12 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 b            7        4          23        26
13 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 b            8        5          26        29
14 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 b            9        6          29        32
15 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 b           10        7          32        35
16 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 b            7        4          35        28
17 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 b            8        5          28        31
18 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 b            9        6          31        34
19 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 b           10        7          34        37
20 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 b           11        8          37        40
```

Answer (score 0):

With tidyverse, try:

```
library(tidyverse)

intial %>%
  arrange(group, id, start_date) %>%
  group_by(group, id) %>% 
  mutate(delta = if_else(is.na(start_count), 
                         true = increase - decrease, 
                         false = 0L),
         end_count = if_else(is.na(end_count), 
                             true = cumsum(delta) + last(na.omit(end_count)), 
                             false = end_count ),
         start_count = if_else(is.na(start_count), 
                               true = lag(end_count), 
                               false = start_count)) %>% 
  select(-delta) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 20 x 8
   start_date end_date      id group increase decrease start_count end_count
   <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>    <int>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 a            4        1          10        13
 2 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 a            5        2          13        16
 3 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 a            6        3          16        19
 4 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 a            7        4          19        22
 5 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 a            8        5          22        25
 6 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 a            5        2          15        18
 7 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 a            6        3          18        21
 8 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 a            7        4          21        24
 9 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 a            8        5          24        27
10 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 a            9        6          27        30
11 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1 b            6        3          20        23
12 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     1 b            7        4          23        26
13 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     1 b            8        5          26        29
14 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     1 b            9        6          29        32
15 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     1 b           10        7          32        35
16 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     2 b            7        4          25        28
17 2021-07-01 2021-08-01     2 b            8        5          28        31
18 2021-08-01 2021-09-01     2 b            9        6          31        34
19 2021-09-01 2021-10-01     2 b           10        7          34        37
20 2021-10-01 2021-11-01     2 b           11        8          37        40
```